# Java Neo4j Deletion and Internal 500 Errors

Tags: java, neo4j

When I delete my neo4j database after my tests like this

```
  public static final DatabaseOperation clearDatabaseOperation = new DatabaseOperation() {
    @Override public void performOperation(GraphDatabaseService db) {

        //This is deprecated on the GraphDatabaseService interface,
        // but the alternative is not supported by implementation (RestGraphDatabase)
        for (Node node : db.getAllNodes()) {
            for (Relationship relationship : node.getRelationships()) {
                relationship.delete();
            }

            boolean notTheRootNode = node.getId() != 0;
            if (notTheRootNode) {
                node.delete();
            }
        }
```

When querying the database through an ajax search (i.e searching on an empty database it returns an internal 500 error)

```
localhost:9000/search-results?keywords=t 500 Internal Server Error
        197ms
```

However if I delete the database manually like this

```
start r=relationship(*) delete r;
start n=node(*) delete n;
```

No exception is thrown

Its most likely an issue with my code at a lower level in the call and return.

Just wandering why the error only works on one of the scenarios above and not both

Answer (score 0):

Use cypher,

you should probably state more obviously that you use the rest-graph-database.

Are you querying after the deletion or during it?

Please check your logs in `data/graph.db/messages.log` and `data/log/console.log` to find the error cause.

Perhaps you can also look at the response body of the http-500 request

Answer (score 0):

As per your error I guess your data is getting corrupted after deletion.

I have used same code like yours and deleted the nodes, except I put the Iterator in transaction and shut down the database after opetation.

e.g.

```
Transaction _tx = _db.beginTx();
    try {
        for ( your conditions){             
            Your code
        }
        _tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        _tx.finish();
        _db.shutdown();
        graphDbFactory.cleanUp();
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.